# How do you correctly convert Immutable Map to strictly typed using Typescript

Tags: typescript, immutability, immutable.js

How can I convert the following from js to Typescript:

```
Immutable.Map({
   item1: null,
   item2: "hello",
   item3: Immutable.Map({
     item4: 2,
     item5: true
   })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the immutable.js framework, but I would suggest using a standard JavaScript map. Typescript has the type `ReadonlyMap` which basically removes all the setters from the map object. The object itself will not really be imputable (aka. no runtime error), but the typescript compiler will complain if you try to add/remove/update values.

```js
const myMap: ReadonlyMap<string, string> = new Map([
    ['item1', 'foo'],
    ['item2', 'bar']
]);

console.log(myMap.get('item1')); // will log foo

myMap.set('item1', 'foobar'); // Property set does not exist on type readonly map
```

*A bit off topic but I would suggest re-rethinking your map structure. Sure `string | null` is fine. But `string | null | ReadonlyMap<string, number | boolean>` does sound like a wird map (to me).*

Also, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is the map documentation if you care to have a read.

Comment: Immutable doesn't mean non-modifiable, it means when you want to modify it you get a modified copy while original data structure keeps unchanged.

    const x = Immutable.Map();
    const y = x.set('a', 'aa');
    const z = y.set('b', 'bb');
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
    console.log(z);

output:

    {}
    {a: "aa"}
    {a: "aa", b: "bb"}

Comment: @den_po Immutable is a word that means something cannot be changed. If a library decides to "treat" their objects as immutable, and return modified copies, that is a design choice. This fact does not make something mutable, or immutable.

Comment: please google for "immutable data structures"

Comment: @den_po the first result that comes up for me is the rust documentation: https://docs.rs/im/latest/im/. And I'm quite familiar with rust. In rust, immutable variables have to be cloned first (using the `clone()`) method, through it, you can obtain a clone of the struct that is mutable (This can also be achieved implicitly through the `Copy` trait, but that is usually reserved for simple types like numbers). In no way is "cloning" necessary for immutability, it's only necessary if you want to modify data and operate on it. You can have types and thus structures that aren't "cloneable".

Comment: Anyway, this is off-topic and shouldn't be discussed here.

Comment: Nope, this is not offtopic. Topicstarter asks about immutable.js - a library implementing immutable collections - the ones which generally CAN be modified, not in place but by creating updated copies.

Comment: @den_po as I've stated in my answer, I don't know how it works in immutable.js. It might very well be that it works this way in this library, but that is a different statement from `Immutable doesn't mean non-modifiable`. I'm 100% sure that *generally* immutable means exactly this. It even means *this* in the current context. Since you **need to create a copy**. You literarily can't modify the original data, which is the definition of immutability.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
type Immutable<T> = {
  readonly [K in keyof T]: Immutable<T[K]>;
};

// Then you could write your interface 
interface Person {
  name: string;
  lastName: string;
  address: {
    street: string;
    zipCode: number;
  }
}

const person: Immutable<Person> = {
  name: 'joe',
  lastName: 'smith',
  address: {
    street: 'smith street',
    zipCode: 55555
  }
}

// Then when you try to mutate, typescript should throw an error that it is a readonly property
person.name = 'alice';
person.address.street = 'ano'
```

Credit goes to the author of this article linked here: https://www.sitepoint.com/compile-time-immutability-in-typescript/